# Mapping Hadoop `FileStatus` back to URI base relative path

Tags: hadoop, path, uri

I'm running a Hadoop map reduce job that uses some `FileSystem` implementation. When I ask the `FileSytem` for the `FileStatus` of the root path `/`, it gives me back a `FileStatus` with the `FileStatus.getPath()` set to `foo://bar/`. Naturally this `Path.toUri()` returns `foo://bar/`.

Apparently the `FileSystem` implementation I'm using interprets a "bare" absolute path as relative to some context URI. (This reminds me of Java EE servlet context mapping, where an absolute servlet path `/bar` would be interpreted relative to some context base path `/foo/`, yielding `/foo/bar`.)

That's all well and good, but how do I map the other way? Given some `FileStatus` with a `FileStatus.getPath()` returning `foo://bar/`, how can I get back the original "bare" path of `/`?

(Or is it the case that this particular `FileStatus` implementation is buggy, and `FileStatus.getPath()` should be returning `/` to begin with? I cannot find any Hadoop `FileSystem` documentation that describes how this should work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it may appear to be part of the path, the `bar` part of `foo://bar/` is really the URI authority as explained in the [`java.net.URI` API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html)—analogous to `example.com` in the URL `https://example.com/test.html`. Thus to get the original path back, one needs to call `FileStatus.getPath().toUri().getPath()`, which will return the part of the URI after the authority.